# insert con select en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde creo una tabla y le quiero insertar informacion que saco de una consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE AR_TABLA_REORI (TER VARCHAR(50),REG VARCHAR(50),ORIGEN INT, CLIENTES INT, TOTAL INT,SUCORIGEN INT)

INSERT INTO AR_TABLA_REORI VALUES (TER ,REG ,ORIGEN ,CLIENTES )
SELECT TERL,REG,ORIGEN, COUNT(*) AS SUCORIGEN 
FROM CLIENTES_TBL
```

Tipos de dato de la tabla `CLIENTES_TBL`

```
TER nvarchar(510)
REG nvarchar(510)
ORIGEN INT
CLIENTES INT
```

Tengo el siguiente error:

> The name "TER" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are
>   constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Podrias agregar la estructura de la tabla CLIENTES_TBL para ver el tipo de datos.

Comment: Ya muestro los tipos de dato

Comment: Quita la palabra VALUES...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Values` esta de mas en la sentencia, `insert select`

```
INSERT INTO AR_TABLA_REORI (TER ,REG ,ORIGEN ,CLIENTES )
SELECT TERL,REG,ORIGEN, COUNT(*) 
FROM CLIENTES_TBL
```